# Hailstones and the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: haskell, collatz-sequence

The [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is related to a type of problem called a Hailstone problem; because hailstones circulate up and down through a cloud around a planet until they eventually fall. The Collatz conjecture posits that for the function

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} \text{even: } & n/2\\ \text{odd: } & 3n+1\end{cases}
$$

the sequence \$n, f(n), f(f(n)), \cdots, f^i(n), \cdots\$ will eventually arrive at the value 1.

The following example code, which calculates the sum of all even [members of the sequence obtained for a given starting value \$n\$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HailstoneNumber.html), is given as part of an exercise, but I'm looking to improve it. By improving it, I mean: shorten via composition; via mapping; via folding; or any other more powerful and better practice.

> ```
> foo :: Integer -> Integer
> foo 1 = 0
> foo n 
>   | even n    = n + foo (n `div` 2)
>   | otherwise = foo (3 * n + 1)
> ```

Here's what I got. I'm using point-free style with composition  in `foo'`. However, I'm not so sure how to improve `f`.

```
foo' :: Integer -> Integer
foo' = (sum . f)

f :: Integer -> [Integer]
f x 
 | x == 1    = []
 | even x    = x : f (x `div` 2)
 | otherwise = f (3*x + 1)
```

Please critique this improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every piece of code should have a clear purpose. If you need to conduct some maintenance on a piece of code, you obtain its description first. You consult users, manuals, previous developers as needed.

I assume this code is bug-free and it's doing some calculation on some hailstone numbers.

First of all, you extracting the implicit sequence is an improvement on the original, *provided we know we are dealing with a sequence*.

### Further improvements

That only even numbers are included in the sum is not part of the Collatz Problem. By moving the condition we can rename the unnamed sequence as `hailstones`. Also `f` is not a good name for a sequence, as `f` and `g` usually denote parameters which are functions.

```
foo' :: Integer -> Integer
foo' = sum . filter even . hailstones -- removed unnecessary parentheses

hailstones :: Integer -> [Integer]
hailstones x 
 | x == 1    = []
 | even x    = x : hailstones (x `div` 2)
 | otherwise = x : hailstones (3 * x + 1) -- space around *
```

Stopping condition is not part of the original Collatz problem, either. Hailstone sequences do not stop at 1, but rather go  \$ \cdots, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, \cdots \$ forever.

```
foo' :: Integer -> Integer
foo' = sum . filter even . takeWhile (/= 1) . hailstones

hailstones :: Integer -> [Integer]
hailstones x 
 | even x    = x : hailstones (x `div` 2)
 | otherwise = x : hailstones (3 * x + 1)
```

Make the recursive nature of these sequences explicit:

```
collatzStep n
 | even n    = n `div` 2
 | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

hailstones x = x : collatzStep x
```

Last line can be written as `hailstones = iterate collatzStep`.

Altogether:

```
collatzStep n
 | even n    = n `div` 2
 | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

hailstones = iterate collatzStep

foo' = sum . filter even . takeWhile (/= 1) . hailstones
```

Now, of course if you were to hand this in as a homework, TAs or the professor would have asked you to add a lot of comments. First of all you do not tell them that "Comments are a code smell." Or describe what you did as KISS, DRY, readability etc.

Since this probably is a Programming Languages homework, you should add a comment mentioning that `collatzStep` is "lambda lifted", not "factored out"; that `hailstones` is an anamorphism and this, of course, makes `foo` an hylomorphism (correct the greek, and add more of it as <del>necessary</del> desired).